# Number length undetermined inside regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have this line with a regex:

```
user.image.gsub(%r{(http://graph.facebook.com/\d{15}/picture\?type=)\w+}, '\1large')
```

The profile image URL can be:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/12/picture?type=square
http://graph.facebook.com/123/picture?type=square
http://graph.facebook.com/1234/picture?type=square
http://graph.facebook.com/12345679/picture?type=square
```

The `length number` inside the URL, is undetermined.

How I can use this regular expression to match any length number inside this URL?

I tried with:

```
user.image.gsub(%r{(http://graph.facebook.com/\d/picture\?type=)\w+}, '\1large')
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user.image.gsub(%r{(http://graph.facebook.com/\d+/picture\?type=)\w+}, '\1large')
                                 add a + here __^
```